# removing just one of double indexes

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, series

Is given a *pandas.core.series.Series* consisting of two *pandas.core.series.Series:*

```
S1 = pd.concat([S,S])
e.g.:|index| value    |
     | --- | -------- |
     |4707 | 25.408939|
     |13292| 24.288939|
     |38063| 22.766040|
     |39458|-16.478080|
     |39571|-15.085605|
     **|4707 | 25.408939|**
     |13292| 24.288939|
     |38063| 22.766040|
     |39458|-16.478080|
     |39571|-15.085605|
```

where repeated indexes are repeated intentionally.
I can't figure out, how can I delete just one of those repeated rows, for example row in bold.

extra info:

```
print(type(S1))
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

print(type(S1[S1.index[i]]))
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `|` for bitwise `OR` with mask by [`Index.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.duplicated.html) with inverting by `~` and test not match value `4707`:

```
S2 = S1[~S1.index.duplicated() | (S1.index != 4707)]

print (S2)
4707   25.408939
13292  24.288939
38063  22.766040
39458 -16.478080
39571 -15.085605
13292  24.288939
38063  22.766040
39458 -16.478080
39571 -15.085605
```

Or simply remove value in `pd.concat`:

```
S1 = pd.concat([S,S.drop(4707)])
```